# R ggplot2 stacked barplot normalized by the value of a column

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe `t` :

```
name type total
a    1    20
a    1    20
a    3    20
a    2    20
a    3    20
b    1    25
b    2    25
c    5    35
c    5    35
c    6    35
c    1    35
```

The `total` is the identical for all the entries with the same `name`. 
I want to plot a stacked barplot with `type` on the  `x axis` and `count of name` normalized by the `total` on the `y axis`. 
I plotted the **non normalized plot** by the following :

```
ggplot(t, aes(type,fill= name))+geom_bar() + geom_bar(position="fill")
```

How can I plot the **normalized barplot** ? i.e for `type = 1` the y axis value would be `2/20` for `a` and `1/25` for `b` and `1/35` for `c`...

My try which did not work:

```
ggplot(t, aes(type, ..count../t$total[1],fill= name))+geom_bar() + geom_bar(position="fill")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Read in the data

```
d <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
'name type total
a    1    20
a    1    20
a    3    20
a    2    20
a    3    20
b    1    25
b    2    25
c    5    35
c    5    35
c    6    35
c    1    35')
```

It's a bad idea to call it `t`, since that is the name of the transpose function.

### Calculate the fractions

```
library(dplyr)
d2 <- d %>% 
  group_by(name, type) %>% 
  summarize(frac = n() / first(total))
```

This is much easier to do using the `dplyr` package.

### Make the plot

```
ggplot(d2, aes(type, frac, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

### Result

[image]